# Implement a web server based on REST Architecture in android

Tags: android, rest

I wanna to implement a **web server in android**, based on **REST architecture**. This web server receives special commands based on REST, decode them, do requested task(s) and return result to client.

I'm a novice in android programing and also in web based servers and REST architecture.Can any body give me a step bye step help to do this.

Thanks very much.

Comment: what is your programming language server side ?

Comment: REST is not a protocol.

Comment: My server must be an android app that receives REST based requests and do appropriate tasks and get result back to client.Client can be any program on local machine, local network or internet.

Answer (score 0):

**Client Side use :**

1. **Spring for Android** as REST Client
2. **Jackson** library for (serialization/deserialization)
3. Use **Hibernate reverse engineering** to generate your beans

**Server Side :**

1. For java : [REST with Java (JAX-RS)](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html)
2. For Php : [Symfony2 REST API](http://welcometothebundle.com/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/)

Comment: Thank you SELMANON. I saw link 1,but i couldn't find a clear step by step way to implement an android app as a server. I said that I'm a novice. I'm looking for a clear step by step way to do this.A sample program can be helpful.

Comment: @ebi which language you are using ?

Comment: To implement android app I use eclipse IDE with ADT plugin.So my default language is java.

Comment: @ebi i mean server side ont client side

Comment: SELMANON, excuse me, I think,the problem wasn't explained clear 
enough.I wanna to implement an android app that acts as a server, based on HTTP protocol under rest architecture.So my app will be run on an android device and listening to a special port, and when receives a request(HTTP request) process it, do appropriate action and return result back to the client.So in this problem the goal is develop an android app that acts exactly as a server in an android device.

Comment: @ebi this is not possible because android device isn't a server

Comment: SELMANON: Why?A server is a program that gets some requests, processes them and gets results back to clients.There is some android programs that do this, such as kWS on Google play or http://hackaday.com/2012/06/21/using-an-android-as-a-webserver/.